# How to get cart rule id when cart rule apply

Tags: magento2, shopping-cart-price-rules

How to get shopping cart rule information? I need to change/add custom logic when the cart rule apply in the shopping cart page.

Answer (score 2):

Magento2 save current applied cart rules at **quote table**. It means you can get applied rules id from **quote object**.

First look at database table `quote` at `applied_rule_ids` columns Magento save respective cart rules id.

[image: table view]

Comment: When i'm going to shopping cart page, I need to get current cart rule id and need to change cart rule logic based on respective prodcuts/customers

Comment: Thanks @amit bera its help me to get a applied_rule_id